# How to initilize a dictonary to some value in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to set a default value to element of the dictornary, following is my playbook showing incorrect way to set the value. Can someone tell to set `dictname.key.value` to `default`. ?

```
 -->cat initilize_dict.yml
---

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dictname:
      key: 'default'
      value: 'default'

  tasks:
   - debug: var=dictname.key.value
   - debug: var=dictname.key.['value']
```

Current output

```
 -->ansible-playbook  initilize_dict.yml
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source
 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dictname.key.value": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{dictname.key.['value']}}"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/monk/samples/initilize_dict.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: What output result do you expect?

Comment: @k0chan  I am trying to set `dictname.key.value` to `default` ,I am asking this because, this dictionary will be set by different task but I need to use it with default value.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use following syntax:

```
- set_fact:
    dictname:
      key:
        { 'value': 'default' }
```

To validate:

```
- debug: var=dictname.key.value
```